# How can I print Khmer Language in Bluetooth Thermal Printer in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, printing, thermal-printer

[Click here to see image of Receipt I was trying to print with Khmer Language but it was converted to Chinese characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ChPN.jpg)
I use Thermal Printer to print text for my local language, but it doesn't work. I can't print only English and Chinese. I use Bluetooth_Printer and it didn't work. Please help me to fix this.

I expected to see my local Language in the receipt.

Comment: Language support will be hardware dependent.  Does your printer support the language you are trying to use?

Comment: Most thermal printers do not support UTF-8 or UTF-16 and work with SBCS/MBCS codepages. However, Khmer seems to have no published code page. ESC/POS used by many printers have multiple Thai codepages, and one of them may be applicable to Khmer. [ESC t](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=32) Otherwise, you'd be creating a bitmap image of everything you want to print and then printing that.